# Android Studio code completion with parameters

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

In Eclipse auto completing method adds default parameters. 
for example, let say that i have the next method:

```
public void setPosition(float x, float y){
...
}
```

When pressing `setp` with `CTRL` + `SPACE` it would suggest me setPosition and add x and y parameters
so the result would be:

```
setPosition(x,y);
```

But with Android Studio the result is:

```
setPosition();
```

Is it possible in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Android Studio. You can use regular completion (Ctrl-Space) or smart type completion (Ctrl-Shift-Space) to complete each of the parameters in the call individually.

Comment: Can't believe, that this is not possible, very sad.